# Get result of Webservice Call as Block Callback with NSURLSession in Swift2

Tags: ios, callback, swift2, objective-c-blocks, nsurlsession

I want to get the result of a webservice call as a block callback so I have added the method `fetchOpportunities` below to my `Opportunity` model class now I want to call this method from my `UIViewController` like that:

```
class HomeViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

     Opportunity.fetchOpportunities( 
           success (data) {

         }
      ) 

  }
}
```

I guess blocks is not present in Swift but how to replicate a similar behavior ? The call is asynchronous but I need to get the data when the call is completed in my `TableViewController` to update the `TableView`and it can't work with my actual implementation in `Objective-C` I used to use blocks but what to do with `Swift2`

Here is the implementation of `fetchOpportunities`

```
class func fetchOpportunities() {

    let urlPath = "http://www.MY_API_HERE.com"

    guard let endpoint = NSURL(string: urlPath) else { print("Error creating endpoint");return }

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:endpoint)

    NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        do {
            guard let dat = data else { throw JSONError.NoData }
            guard let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(dat, options: []) as? NSDictionary else { throw JSONError.ConversionFailed }

            var ops = [Opportunity]()

            if let dataArray = json["data"] as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
                for op in dataArray {
                    ops.append(  Opportunity(op) )
                }
            }

            print(ops)

        } catch let error as JSONError {
            print(error.rawValue)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

Comment: It is called a closure in Swift but it is the same thing. They are covered in the Swift book.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look and try to do the same as I used to with Obj-C

Answer (score 0):

Just use closure. The method declaration will be:

```
class func fetchOpportunities(callback: ([Opportunity]) -> ()) {

 // Do all the work here and then send the data like :

  callback(ops)     

}
```

In `UIViewController`:

```
    Opportunity.fetchOpportunities { (data) -> () in
        print(data)
    }
```

[Efficient JSON in Swift with Functional Concepts and Generics](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/efficient-json-in-swift-with-functional-concepts-and-generics)

[Learn NSURLSession using Swift Part 1](https://medium.com/swift-programming/learn-nsurlsession-using-swift-ebd80205f87c)